# My Samsung Galaxy GT-S5830i wants to force stop everything

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

The phone starts up normally and then when I enter my password but then I am immediately greeted by: 'Sorry! The application (process com.android.) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.' and a Force close button underneath for every service and application.

Comment: this can be a software issue or even hardware issue. Did you try flashing it?

Comment: I haven't done anything to it at all I did was take a picture on whatsap and it stopped so I took the battery out and put it back in and from then on this has been happening.

Comment: So you need to factory reset it then. Use key combo (Volume up + Home while powering up)

Comment: That is what I have been doing.

Comment: this seems likely a hardware issue. you should bring the phone to a repair shop, they should be able to fix it

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer I ordered a new one for less than it costs to repair it now but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90504/discussion-between-john-mobey-and-esqmo).